# Problem with showing elapsed time in python

Tags: python, time

I have a problem with function time.time().
I've written a code, which has 3 different hash functions and then it counts how long does they execute.

```
start_time = time.time()
arr.add(Book1, 1)
end_time = time.time()
elapsed_time = start_time - end_time
print(elapsed_time)
```

When I execute this in pycharm/IDLE/Visual it shows 0. When I do this in online compiler (https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/) it shows a good result. Why is that?

Here is the full code if needed.

```
import time


class Ksiazka:
    def __init__(self, nazwa, autor, wydawca, rok, strony):
        self.nazwa = nazwa
        self.autor = autor
        self.wydawca = wydawca
        self.rok = rok
        self.strony = strony

    def hash_1(self):
        h = 0
        for char in self.nazwa:
            h += ord(char)
        return h

    def hash_2(self):
        h = 0
        for char in self.autor:
            h += ord(char)
        return h

    def hash_3(self):
        h = self.strony + self.rok
        return h


class HashTable:
    def __init__(self):
        self.size = 6
        self.arr = [None for i in range(self.size)]

    def add(self, key, c):
        if c == 1:
            h = Ksiazka.hash_1(key) % self.size
            print("Hash 1: ", h)
        if c == 2:
            h = Ksiazka.hash_2(key) % self.size
            print("Hash 2: ", h)
        if c == 3:
            h = Ksiazka.hash_3(key) % self.size
            print("Hash 3: ", h)
        self.arr[h] = key




arr = HashTable()
Book1 = Ksiazka("Harry Potter", "J.K Rowling", "foo", 1990, 700)

start_time = time.time()
arr.add(Book1, 1)
end_time = time.time()
elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
print(elapsed_time)


start_time = time.time()
arr.add(Book1, 2)
end_time = time.time()
elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
print(elapsed_time)

start_time = time.time()
arr.add(Book1, 3)
end_time = time.time()
elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
print(elapsed_time)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The documentation for `time.time` says:](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time)

> Note that even though the time is always returned as a floating point number, not all systems provide time with a better precision than 1 second. While this function normally returns non-decreasing values, it can return a lower value than a previous call if the system clock has been set back between the two calls.

So, depending on your OS, anything that is faster than 1 second might be displayed as a difference of `0`.

I suggest you use [`time.perf_counter` instead](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter):

> Return the value (in fractional seconds) of a performance counter, i.e. a clock with the highest available resolution to measure a short duration.

Comment: Nice! Now it works. I had to use time.perf_counter_ns, because without it numbers were too strange ( like    9.400000000003156e-06). But when i change it to ns time is finally good. Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is strange about that? `9.4e-06` just means 9.4 x 10^-6, i.e. 0.0000094s (or 9.4µs).

Comment: Yeah. I never know how to read that. I have to learn it finally. Thanks.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, please remember to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I looks like 0 might just be a return value for successful script execution. You need to add a print statement to show anything. Also you might want to change the order of the subtraction:

```
start_time = time.time()
arr.add(Book1, 1)
end_time = time.time()
elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
print(elapsed_time)
```

**Edit b/c of updated questions:**

If it still shows 0, it might just happen, that your add operation is extremely fast. In that case, try averaging over several runs, i.e. instead of your add operation use a version like this:

```
start_time = time.time()
for _ in range(10**6):
    arr.add(Book1, 1)
end_time = time.time()
elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
print(elapsed_time)  # indicates the average microseconds for a single run
```

Comment: I did it. I just forget to copy it to this post (I've just edited post and fix it). Problem is that the result is 0 instead of some numbers.

Comment: Can you edit you post, and add some more code. I cannot access pastebin from here.

Comment: Yeah. Give me a second.

Comment: How much time does the online compiler show? Does my edit, i.e. multiple repetitions, help you?

Comment: E.g  5.4836273193359375e-06. It's strange number. But I have tried to do this on cmd too. There are numbers like 0.0059833526611328125

Comment: does it help to use multiple runs? does it still show zero, if you replace `arr.add(..)` by `time.sleep(2)`